# Fortran error 256 when calling a function to return an array

Tags: arrays, matrix, fortran, gaussian

I'm writing a program to take a 2D array in, being 3 coefficients and 1 solution for each equation, then solving for variables X, Y, and Z. My problem is with the basic row functions swap, scale, and pivot, which all effect a given row in the matrix. Right now, I'm using the functions to replace the input expression matrix when the function is complete, the error occurs whenever I call on each of the row functions. **I am using the Plato IDE and the FTN95 compiler**

```
Compiling and linking file: src.f95
C:\Users\vv3383my\Documents\School\Programs\Simultaneous Expression Solver\bin\src.F95(59) : error 256 - INTEGER expression expected in array bounds subscript
C:\Users\vv3383my\Documents\School\Programs\Simultaneous Expression Solver\bin\src.F95(62) : error 256 - INTEGER expression expected in array bounds subscript
C:\Users\vv3383my\Documents\School\Programs\Simultaneous Expression Solver\bin\src.F95(65) : error 256 - INTEGER expression expected in array bounds subscript
C:\Users\vv3383my\Documents\School\Programs\Simultaneous Expression Solver\bin\src.F95(67) : error 256 - INTEGER expression expected in array bounds subscript
C:\Users\vv3383my\Documents\School\Programs\Simultaneous Expression Solver\bin\src.F95(69) : error 256 - INTEGER expression expected in array bounds subscript
C:\Users\vv3383my\Documents\School\Programs\Simultaneous Expression Solver\bin\src.F95(71) : error 256 - INTEGER expression expected in array bounds subscript
C:\Users\vv3383my\Documents\School\Programs\Simultaneous Expression Solver\bin\src.F95(73) : error 256 - INTEGER expression expected in array bounds subscript
Compilation failed.
```

My code is listed below:

```
program expSolver

!declare variables
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: n=10
  integer, parameter :: expCount=3
  real, dimension(n,4) :: exp
  real :: sol(expCount)
  real :: rowEchelon
  !basically a for loop
  !do i=1,n
  !  print*, i
  !enddo

  exp(1,1)=2
  exp(1,2)=12
  exp(1,3)=17
  exp(1,4)=-32
  exp(2,1)=-3
  exp(2,2)=-7
  exp(2,3)=-8
  exp(2,4)=6
  exp(3,1)=1
  exp(3,2)=4
  exp(3,3)=6
  exp(3,4)=-7

  call printArr(exp, expCount, n)
  sol(3) = rowEchelon(exp, expCount, n)
  print*,sol(3)
end program

subroutine printArr(exp, expCount, n)
  integer :: expCount, n
  real exp(n,4)
  integer :: i
  do i=1,expCount
    write(*,*) exp(i,1), exp(i,2), exp(i,3), "|", exp(i,4)
  enddo
  return
end
!Puts augmented matrix into row echelon for and returns for z
real function rowEchelon(exp, expCount, n)
  implicit none
  real :: rowEchelon
  integer :: x=-1
  integer :: expCount, n
  integer :: i
  real, dimension(n,4) :: exp
  real, dimension(n,4) :: swapRow, scaleRow, pivotRow
  print*, "Putting matrix into row echelon form..."
  do i=1, expCount
    if(exp(i,1) == 1.0)then
      x=i
    endif
  enddo
  if(.NOT.(x == -1))then
    print*, "swap"
    exp = swapRow(exp, n, 1, x)
  else
    print*, "scale"
    exp = scaleRow(exp, n, 1, real(1/exp(1,1)))
  endif
  print*, "pivot"
  exp = pivotRow(exp, n, 2, 1, real(-(exp(2,1))))
  print*, "pivot"  
  exp = pivotRow(exp, n, 3, 1, real(-(exp(3,1))))
  print*, "scale"
  exp = scaleRow(exp, n, 2, real(1/exp(2,2)))
  print*, "pivot"
  exp = pivotRow(exp, n, 3, 2, real(-(exp(3,2))))
  print*, "scale"
  exp = scaleRow(exp, n, 3, real(1/exp(3,3)))
  rowEchelon = exp(3,4)
  return
end
!Matrix function swap row take the index of 2 rows and swaps their contents
function swapRow(exp, n, index1, index2)
  implicit none
  integer :: n, index1, index2, i
  real, dimension(n,4) :: swapRow, exp
  swapRow = exp
  do i=1, 4
    swapRow(index1, i) = exp(index2, i)
    swapRow(index2, i) = exp(index1, i)
  enddo
  call printArr(swapRow)
  return
end function swapRow
!Matrix function scale row multiplies all values in a row by a given factor
function scaleRow(exp, n, index, fac) 
  integer :: n, index, i
  real :: fac
  real :: exp(n, 4)
  real, dimension(n, 4) :: scaleRow
  scaleRow = exp
  do i=1, 4
    scaleRow(index, i) = exp(index, i) * fac
  enddo
  call printArr(scaleRow)
  return
end
!Matrix function pivot row multiplies a row at index 2 by a given factor fac then adds to another row at index 1
function pivotRow(exp, n, index1, index2, fac)
  integer :: n, index1, index2, i
  real :: fac
  real :: exp(n, 4), pivotRow(n, 4)
  pivotRow = exp
  do i=1, 4
    pivotRow(index1, i) = exp(index1, i) + (exp(index2, i) * fac)
  enddo
  call printArr(pivotRow)
  return
end
```

The areas I'm having trouble with is in the function rowEchelon:

```
!Puts augmented matrix into row echelon for and returns for z
real function rowEchelon(exp, expCount, n)
  implicit none
  real :: rowEchelon
  integer :: x=-1
  integer :: expCount, n
  integer :: i
  real, dimension(n,4) :: exp
  real, dimension(n,4) :: swapRow, scaleRow, pivotRow
  print*, "Putting matrix into row echelon form..."
  do i=1, expCount
    if(exp(i,1) == 1.0)then
      x=i
    endif
  enddo
  if(.NOT.(x == -1))then
    print*, "swap"
    exp = swapRow(exp, n, 1, x)
  else
    print*, "scale"
    exp = scaleRow(exp, n, 1, real(1/exp(1,1)))
  endif
  print*, "pivot"
  exp = pivotRow(exp, n, 2, 1, real(-(exp(2,1))))
  print*, "pivot"  
  exp = pivotRow(exp, n, 3, 1, real(-(exp(3,1))))
  print*, "scale"
  exp = scaleRow(exp, n, 2, real(1/exp(2,2)))
  print*, "pivot"
  exp = pivotRow(exp, n, 3, 2, real(-(exp(3,2))))
  print*, "scale"
  exp = scaleRow(exp, n, 3, real(1/exp(3,3)))
  rowEchelon = exp(3,4)
  return
end
```

The row functions themselves are here:

Matrix function swap row take the index of 2 rows and swaps their contents

```
function swapRow(exp, n, index1, index2)
  implicit none
  integer :: n, index1, index2, i
  real, dimension(n,4) :: swapRow, exp
  swapRow = exp
  do i=1, 4
    swapRow(index1, i) = exp(index2, i)
    swapRow(index2, i) = exp(index1, i)
  enddo
  call printArr(swapRow)
  return
end function swapRow
```

Matrix function scale row multiplies all values in a row by a given factor

```
function scaleRow(exp, n, index, fac) 
  integer :: n, index, i
  real :: fac
  real :: exp(n, 4)
  real, dimension(n, 4) :: scaleRow
  scaleRow = exp
  do i=1, 4
    scaleRow(index, i) = exp(index, i) * fac
  enddo
  call printArr(scaleRow)
  return
end
```

Matrix function pivot row multiplies a row at index 2 by a given factor fac then adds to another row at index 1

```
function pivotRow(exp, n, index1, index2, fac)
  integer :: n, index1, index2, i
  real :: fac
  real :: exp(n, 4), pivotRow(n, 4)
  pivotRow = exp
  do i=1, 4
    pivotRow(index1, i) = exp(index1, i) + (exp(index2, i) * fac)
  enddo
  call printArr(pivotRow)
  return
end
```

This is my first time programming in Fortran so I may be missing something obvious, though I did get the program to work in Java, so I know my math is right. Also, I know my program doesn't allow for more expressions and everything is hard-coded, I'm just trying to make sure it can solve this simple matrix first.

Comment: Please show us the complete error output. Including the line number and everything else, all the lines of the output. The error code 256 is completely useless. There is nothing like "Fortran error 256". There are many compilers and each have different error messages and error codes.

Comment: Tell us which compiler doo you use, which version and which compiler flags do you use during compilation.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I have edited the question to include the full output and added that I am using the Plato IDE and FTN95 compiler

Comment: When you call `scaleRow(exp, n, 1, real(1/exp(1,1)))` the calling function things that `scaleRow` is an array, bucause it is declared as `real, dimension(n,4) :: swapRow, scaleRow, pivotRow`. Please see the duplicate link about how to reference array-valued functions.

Comment: Basically, use modules for all your functions and subroutines. That should be done almost always in modern Fortran.

Comment: I've done that now, but I still get the same errors for every call to the row functions.

Comment: You probably did not delete the `real, dimension(n, 4) :: scaleRow` declaration.